# Updating inventory quantities using the Shopify API

Tags: api, shopify

I'm trying to update products using the Shopify API.  Here's a sample XML request to update the title, weight and inventory of a product:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product>
  <id type="integer">100159400</id>
  <title>150 Watt Mini Stereo Power Amplifier</title>
  <variants type="array">
    <variant>
      <id type="integer">233139732</id>
      <grams type="integer">700</grams>
      <inventory-quantity type="integer">222</inventory-quantity>
    </variant>
  </variants>
</product>
```

I get a 200-OK after PUT /admin/products/100159400.xml. The title and weight (grams) get updated just fine, but not the inventory quantity.  This is consistent for all other calls: I can update every field but the inventory quantity.  Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That product does not have inventory tracking turned on. In your admin, you should see that the inventory level shows as infinity.

To change this and start tracking inventory, you need to set the `inventory_management` field on the variant to `shopify`. The following XML should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product>
  <id type="integer">100159400</id>
  <title>150 Watt Mini Stereo Power Amplifier</title>
  <variants type="array">
    <variant>
      <id type="integer">233139732</id>
      <grams type="integer">700</grams>
      <inventory-management>shopify</inventory-management>
      <inventory-quantity type="integer">222</inventory-quantity>
    </variant>
  </variants>
</product>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Can you tell me where I can find more detailed information about what happens in Shopify when a product has inventory tracking turned on?

Comment: Can both of you tell me that how to use PUT. I am just able to GET cURL and POST cURL request. But when I use PUT instead of PUT it does'nt work.